# Devise current_user vs user_id passed in params, nested resources update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-resources

I am using Devise for authentication. I have two models where a user has one profile and profile belong to user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy 
end 

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am using nested resources e.g.

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

To create a new user profile I use the prefix `new_user_profile_path(current_user)` that routes to `prifile#new` etc

To update a user profile I do the following

```
# e.g. users/123/profile
current_user.profile.update(profile_params)
```

This doesn't feel right because I am not using `the user_id => 123` in profile `params`. 
Should I be finding the user profile by user_id instead e.g.

```
@profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])
@profile.update(profile_params)
```

Additionally, user's cannot edit other users' profile.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Answer (score 1):

`current_user.profile.update(profile_params)` is an acceptable way of updating the profile for the current user.

This also helps secure the profile from being edited by another user. If you base the user ID on params passed in from the query string, that is insecure and would allow any logged in user to be able to update another users profile.

For example, using restful routes anyone with access could post to `/users/profiles/:id` even if it wasn't their own ID.

`current_user` is an instance of the User model, and already contains the `user_id` attribute.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and I actually excluded the user_id from permitted params.